# Which distribution for a netbook?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, intel-graphics, ubuntu-netbook

I have a netbook ASUS EEEPC 1015CX SeaShell Series with Integrated graphics, 1GB ram and 1.6GHz processor (ATOM).

I have tried multiple times to get Ubuntu 12.10 on it via LIVE USB "Try Mode" but it didn't boot up, all I saw was a black screen with a white blinking "_".

Once I've installed it through WUBI and when it finished and rebooted the computer some errors started popping up about certain files missing so I've aboreted the install.

I have tried to get 12.04 which worked but graphics only operated at 800×600 which is too small as I can achieve 1024×600 on my W7 Starter.

So here is my question:

**Which Ubuntu version or Ubuntu-based distro is best for my Netbook, and if it is one of the mentioned above can you suggest a fix to the graphics problem?**

**Thanks.**

Comment: check this out: [Are there any Linux distributions specifically designed for netbooks?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38107/14305)

Comment: and this: [What are suitable distros for the Asus EEE PC 701 4G?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26035/14305)

Comment: Ubuntu is just one distro. You think about Ubuntu & Ubuntu-based OSes...

Comment: Thank you for that, however do you have any idea as to where or how to dowload the driver for my graphics cards on Ubuntu 12.04? I am assuming that's the problem for not having the right screen resolution. Is there any command? (I'm a newbie)

Comment: What is your GPU model?

Comment: I am not sure, I know that it is Intel Integrated Graphics. Intel GMA 3600?

Answer (score 1):

For an **Asus Eee PC 1015PN**, it is suggested [in this site](http://mtron.co.nr/howtos/eeepc-1015pn): (*please check that webpage and note that the computer model is differente than yours*)

Correct display resolution: If you can't set the 1024x600 resolution in Gnome's Display Settings open a terminal and type:

```
xrandr
```

which should output something like:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
```

Take note of the name of your laptop's display device. In this example it is `LVDS1`

To get the supported modeline type:

```
cvt 1024 600
```

The output would look like:

```
# 1024x600 59.85 Hz (CVT) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 49.00 MHz
Modeline "1024x600_60.00"   49.00  1024 1072 1168 1312  600 603 613 624 -hsync +vsync"
```

With this info you can now add a new modeline to `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x600_60.00" 49.00 1024 1072 1168 1312 600 603 613 624 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1024x600_60.00
xrandr auto
```

Please note that this might or might not work in your model of computer, and I have not personally tested this. Check the referenced website for more information.